# Voltage in Centre Tapped Transform Full Wave Rectifier

Tags: electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics

From what I understand from the working the peak output potential after rectification should be half that of the secondary coil in the transformer. However, no such thing is mentioned in my textbook; the graph shown in the textbook too says that the input and output potential would be same which I don't understand.
https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/leph206.pdf (Page 18/58)

[image]

However, Wikipedia does say that the potential would be halved unless the number of coil in the secondary circuit is doubled. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier
[image]

I am hoping someone would be able to provide better clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have amended part of one of your diagrams.

[image]

The label $\rm V_{\rm A,CT}$ means the potential of node $\rm A$ relative to the potential of the centre tap node $\rm CT$.

Now just like relative velocities, $\rm V_{\rm A,\color{red} B} + \rm V_{\rm \color{red}B,CT}= \rm V_{\rm A,CT} \Rightarrow \rm V_{\rm A,B} = \rm V_{\rm A,CT}+(- \rm V_{B,CT}) = \rm V_{\rm A,CT}+(+ \rm V_{CT,B})$

Thus you will see that the amplitude of the voltage $\rm V_{\rm A,B}$ is twice that of $\rm V_{\rm A,CT}, \rm V_{\rm B,CT}$ and the output rectified voltage.

Answer (score 1):

In the analysis of a transformer we consider the magnetic flux through the primary and secondary coils. With the assumption that the same flux passes through each turn of the coils, there will be the same voltage produced in each turn of wire in the coils.

Since there are twice as many turns between A and B as there are between A and the centre tap (or the centre tap and B), there will be twice the voltage between A and B as between A and the centre tap (or the centre tap and B).